# How can I cram 6+31 numeric characters into 22 alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, compression, biginteger

I've got a 6-digit number and a 31-digit number (e.g. "234536" & "201103231043330478311223582826") that I need to cram into the same 22-character alphanumeric field in an API using PHP. I tried converting each to base 32 (had to use a custom function as `base_convert()` doesn't handle big numbers well) and joining with a single-character delimiter, but that only gets me down to 26 characters. It's a REST API, so the characters need to be URI-safe.

I'd really like to do this without creating a database table cross referencing the two numbers with another reference value, if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that really 16 digits for the seconds fraction?

Comment: If my math is right, you need to use a base-54 encoding. Case-sensitive alphanumeric encoding (base-62) should be sufficient. Is there some reason why this won't work? Do you need to see the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a radix of 62 instead. That will get you 3.35 characters for the former and 17.3 characters for the latter, for an upper total of 22 characters.

```
>>> math.log(10**6)/math.log(62)
3.3474826039165504
>>> math.log(10**31)/math.log(62)
17.295326786902177
```

Comment: Does this take into account the additional character required to delimit the two numbers?

Comment: If the resultant values are 0-padded then you don't need a delimiter; slicing the string will be enough.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't understand the math to get there, but now I do! So, something like `str_pad($base62Encoded, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` and `str_pad($base62Encoded, 18, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` concatenated together should pad it correctly, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like `pack()` that works with big numbers using bc. Here is my quick solution, it converts your second number in a 13-character string. Pretty nice !

```
<?php
$i2 = "201103231043330478311223582826";

function pack_large($i) {
    $ret = '';
    while(bccomp($i, 0) !== 0) {
        $mod = bcmod($i, 256);
        $i = bcsub($i, $mod);
        $ret .= chr($mod);
        $i = bcdiv($i, 256);
    }

    return $ret;
}

function unpack_large($s) {
    $ret = '0';

    $len = strlen($s);
    for($i = $len - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $add = ord($s[$i]);
        $ret = bcmul($ret, 256);
        $ret = bcadd($ret, $add);
    }

    return $ret;
}

var_dump($i2);
var_dump($pack = pack_large($i2));
var_dump(unpack_large($pack));
```

Sample output :

```
string(30) "201103231043330478311223582826"
string(13) "jàÙl¹9±̉"
string(47) "201103231043330478311223582826.0000000000000000"
```

Since you need URL-friendly characters, use `base64_encode` on the packed string, this will give you a 20-character string (18 if your remove the padding).